# ParserError in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, error, modifiers, function

I wrote the following contract (for educational purposes):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT


pragma solidity 0.8.8;

contract Coin{
    
    holders[] public investors;
    
    mapping(address=>uint256)  public addressToStock;
    mapping(address=>bool)  public addressInvests;

    struct holders{
        address _address;
    }

   

 function deposit(address _address, uint256 _value) public {
    if (addressInvests[_address]==false){
        investors.push(holders(_address));
        addressToStock[_address]=_value;
        addressInvests[_address]=true;
                                        }


      if (addressInvests[_address]==true){
        addressToStock[_address]=addressToStock[_address]+_value;
                                        }
    
    
                                                            }

    function withdraw(address _address, uint256 _value) public {
        addressToStock[_address]=addressToStock[_address]-_value;
        if (addressToStock[_address]==0){
            addressInvests[_address]=false;
        }
    }

    
    function checkBalance(address _address,uint256 _balance) public  returns(bool){
    return addressToStock[_address]<=_balance;

}
```

but it gives following error:

> ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.
> --> artifacts/coin.sol:47:2:
> |
> 47 | }
> |  ^

How to handle this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: As it is mentioned, look at line 47 of the artifacts file and see what's wrong there.
Or put a screenshot here of the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is missing the last curly bracket, which is the closing bracket for the contract
Here is the updated code try this. No major changes just added a bracket at the end.

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT


pragma solidity 0.8.8;

contract Coin{
    
    holders[] public investors;
    
    mapping(address=>uint256)  public addressToStock;
    mapping(address=>bool)  public addressInvests;

    struct holders{
        address _address;
    }

   

 function deposit(address _address, uint256 _value) public {
    if (addressInvests[_address]==false){
        investors.push(holders(_address));
        addressToStock[_address]=_value;
        addressInvests[_address]=true;
                                        }


      if (addressInvests[_address]==true){
        addressToStock[_address]=addressToStock[_address]+_value;
                                        }
    
    
                                                            }

    function withdraw(address _address, uint256 _value) public {
        addressToStock[_address]=addressToStock[_address]-_value;
        if (addressToStock[_address]==0){
            addressInvests[_address]=false;
        }
    }

    
    function checkBalance(address _address,uint256 _balance) public  returns(bool){
    return addressToStock[_address]<=_balance;

}
}
```